# Intuition behind $E[X_3\mid N(t)=2] >$ average jump time

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

> Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson Process of rate λ, let X1, X2, X3, . . . denote the interarrival times,
>   and let S1 = X1, S2 = X1 + X2, . . . be the times of the arrivals (jumps). Compute:
>
> E[X3|N(t) = 2]

My first gut instinct reminds me of the memoryless property of exponential distribution and tells me that the answer is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $E[S3|N(t)=2] = \frac{1}{\lambda} + 2$. However, it is wrong.

I instead used:

> X3 = S3 −S2 = (t−S2)+(S3 −t). Conditional on N(t) = 2, we notice: For the first term, that S2 = max{U1,U2}, where U1,U2 are independent, uniform RV’s on [0, t]. For the second term, that S3 − t is Exp(λ) by the no-memory property. Thus, we have
>   $E[X3|N(t)=2]=t−Emax\{U1,U2\}+E[Exp(λ)]=t−\frac{2}{3}t+\frac{1}{\lambda} =\frac{t}{3} +\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

I can't wrap my head around how the result is $> \frac{1}{\lambda}$, which is the average time for $X_i$. I also would think that since it is unknown that the second occurrence happened exactly, or (most likely) before t, the time to wait for the third occurrence would be shorter than average value $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. If anyone can explain, that will be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose I tell you that $N(s) = 0.$ Then the first interarrival time $X_1$ has the conditional law $s + \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ - the exp is from the memorylessness, but the $s$ is because I've told you that nothing arrived until time $s$. The mistake you're making in your first section is that you're assuming $N(t^-) = 1 $ - you're assuming that the second arrival was at exactly $t$. This need not be.

Comment: The $t/3$ excess in the mean is intuitive - if I told you that until $t$ only $2$ things have arrived, when should you expect the last thing arrived? By memorylessness and identicality, you should expect roughly equal time periods in the range [0, the first arrival, the second arrival, t]. So the last arrival should have, in expectation, occured at $2t/3$.